# In JS, how can you redeclare function parameter variables through desructuring another function?

Tags: javascript

I want to define a variable in a function signature and then re-assign that variable later. The following code is what I am trying to do, but am getting a `Identifier 'b' has already been declared` error:

```
async function test (a, b = 'myTest', c = undefined) {
  let { b, c } = normalizeInput(b, c)
  ...
}
```

The goal is to retain the initial variable names. How can I do this?

Edit: if I remove the `let`, I get `Unexpected token` for the `=`.

Comment: What's wrong with renaming your function arguments? Personally, I advocate against changing values of function arguments.

Comment: In the real case, it seems to make sense to keep them the same. For example, if `b` was `currentTime`, I don't see how renaming it would be ideal. In that case, what would you rename it to?

Comment: It's just variables. Why not create another variable?

Comment: @ReactHelp
I would rename to `normalizedCurrentTime` since you are calling normalizeInput.
Basically whatever the variable name should tell what it holds.

Comment: Great. Thank you all.

Comment: If you really need to leave `currentTime` as is in the rest of the code then rename the argument itself to something like `currentTimeArg`. Otherwise, just like @chiragrtr suggests, rename your new variable to indicate what it really holds.

Comment: @ReactHelp if we look at the facts then chiragrtr's did answer the actual question, so please, mark it as accepted answer unless you actually don't find it so. In the future someone might stumble upon this thread while having the same question as you did and accepting answers to your questions helps building more relevant and friendly knowledge base. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
async function test (a, b = 'myTest', c = undefined) {
  ({ b, c } = normalizeInput(b, c));
  ...
}
```

Read more about need of parentheses [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

Comment: I see. Is this considered "clean" code, or is there a more ideal way to handle this?

Comment: @ReactHelp Since you change the value of variable, it's better to provide a more meaningful name and just use new variables to enhance readability.